# Docker image not exposing

Tags: docker, localhost

I have a docker image which is running perfectly in file I have done

```
EXPOSE 8080
```

and I run my image using

```
sudo docker run -p 8080 <image-name> <Argument1> <Argument2>
```

Image runs but when I go to

```
localhost:8080
```

I get page not found error. Is there no way I can see some response or something on localhost:8080?

Comment: try:
sudo docker run --publish 8080:8080 <image-name> <Argument1> <Argument2>

Comment: Thanx man that worked.Can you tell what was the problem with -p 8080?. I have one more question what if I try some random port like 4567 will that work instead of 8080?

Comment: The answer to your first question is in @Auzias answer.
Of course that you can use another port number rather than 8080. just pay attention to theis two things:
1- make sure that the chosen port number is into this interval [ 1025, 65536]. ports from 0 to 1024 are reserved to previliged services.

2- make sure sure that the chosen port is not used by another service in the host machine.

Comment: Thanx got it. Now its working :)

Comment: I would like to add a few more things to the comment by @MohamedAmjadLASRI. The port "0" is not a port number. If a service request to listen to the port "0", it is processed by the OS as "give me any free number of port that I can use". As for the range < 1024, these ports are not fort privileged _services_ but only accessible to privileged _users_ (which is usually **root** ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option `-p 8080` will expose the container:8080 port into a host:**random**-port.

The option `--publish` works as follow: `-p ip:hostPort:containerPort`. Using a `-P| --publish-all` will automatically bind any container-opened port into random-host port.

It is also possible to publish range of ports: `-p 1234-1236:1222-1224`.