# Not able to access files in xampp htdocs installed in ubuntu docker container

Tags: docker, xampp

I have installed xampp and deployed my php code in a docker image and started a container on ubuntu 14.04.

I cannot access my phpmyadmin by using my docker container system ip/phpmyadmin in host computer's firefox browser , but cannot take my web interface in browser. while try to access my web interface its shows as follows:

```
Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested object. bhla bhla....
Error 403
```

Note: I have already given required permissions to files in xampp/htdocs folder

Comment: What options are your using with `docker run` ? Could you show the full command please?

Comment: sudo docker run -ti ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Running a new container with `sudo docker run -ti ubuntu` will not bind any port. The option `-p` needs to be used to bind host-port from container-port.

See a more [detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35479313/5321002).

In your case, assuming your web server is running on port 80 in the container and assuming you cant to access it from you host web browser on the port 9090 start the container with the command:

`docker run -it -p 9090:80 ubuntu`

Comment: Not working. I can already access xampp dashboard and phpmyadmin. but cant access files in htdocs folder

Comment: What are the logs? Are you sure that the `.htaccess` configuration is read/not overwritten? Try without this `.htaccess`.

Comment: there is no .htaccess file in my root folder

Comment: my codes are under a directory in  htdocs folder, no file in that folder runnig. But try to call a test.php file that copied in htdocs its works